# Create Picklist using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

I am using Metadata API to create various fields. For most part it works, but not for Picklist type. Seems like I am missing picklistValues[]

API version 39

This is working

```
customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = sObj + '.Text__c';
customField.label = 'Test';
customField.type_x = 'Text';
customField.description = 'Test.';
customField.length = 255;
customFields.add(customField);
```

This is NOT working

```
customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = sObj + '.Segment__c';
customField.label = 'Segment';
customField.type_x = 'Picklist';
customField.description = '';
customFields.add(customField);
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating picklist using Metadata API, use the following code:

```
customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = sObj + '.Segment__c';
customField.label = 'Segment';
customField.type_x = 'Picklist';
customField.description = '';

//Create the valueSet for picklist type
MetadataService.ValueSet picklistValueSet = new MetadataService.ValueSet();

//For each ValueSet, we have either ValueSetValuesDefinition or ValueSettings and some other attributes
MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition valueDefinition = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

List<MetadataService.CustomValue> values = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();

MetadataService.CustomValue customValue1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
customValue1.fullName = ''; //API name of picklist value
customValue1.default = true/false;
customValue1.description = '';
customValue1.isActive = true/false;
customValue1.label = '';
values.add(customValue1);

//It will be list of CustomValue
valueDefinition.value = values;
valueDefinition.sorted = false/true;

//set the valueSetDefinition
picklistValueSet.valueSetDefinition = valueDefinition;

//Set the valueSet for picklist type
customField.valueSet = picklistValueSet;
customFields.add(customField);
```

**Description**: For picklist, we need to set the `valueset` attribute which is of type `ValueSet`.

For type `ValueSet`, create `valueSetDefinition` which is of type `ValueSetValuesDefinition`.

For type `ValueSetValuesDefinition`, create `value` which is of type List of `CustomValue`.

Refer [Metadata API types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm)

Comment: Thank you Ankita, I tried above but it won't create picklist field. There are no errors and I can see the picklist field in debug log. I looked at this document and it does suggest same thing as well: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello Ankita. I was looking at this again, and it is throwing an error message - "You must specify either picklist, globalPicklist, or valueSet" As per the code, it is creating valueSet. Any clue what is missing?

Comment: Ankita, do you have an example for a global value set?